# How to select a record that is between two dateranges and two input parameters StartDate and EndDate in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

In my database I have a group which can be active in a week with opening hours.
Group A Startdate: 22-10-2012 EndDate: 28-10-2012 (Startdate is always beginning of the week)
Group A Startdate: 29-10-2012 EndDate: 04-11-2012 (Always end of the week)

Group A has two different opening hours in this two weeks.

Now I have a stored procedure that returns the active group by looking the input parameters StartDate and EndDate. If this two parameters are between the startdate and end date of ONE week then I'm getting the right opening hours.

But when the input parameters are about TWO weeks (Begindate: 22-10-2012 and EndDate: 30-10-2012) then I get the opening hours of two weeks.

```
declare @Begindate datetime    
set @Begindate = '2012-10-22'

declare @Enddate datetime   
set @Enddate = '2012-11-02'


SELECT Id, Date, ..., ...   
FROM Table1 t1  
INNER JOIN Combinations c ON t1.Id=c.Table1Id
INNER JOIN Group g ON c.GroupId=g.Id  
WHERE t1.Date<= @Enddate) AND (t1.Date>= @Begindate  (gets dates I need)   
AND g.BeginDate <=@Enddate and g.Enddate >= @Begindate (Gets active groups)


Some table data:

Table1:

Id    Date         GroupId
1     2012-10-23   10
1     2012-10-29   10



Combinations: (holds the relation between Table1 and Group)

ID  Table1Id    GroupId
1   10          1


Group Table:

ID    Name     StartDate   EndDate     MondayOpen   MondayClose ...
1     Group A  2012-10-22  2012-10-28  08:00        18:00
1     Group A  2012-10-29  2012-11-04  13:00        18:00
```

With this query I am getting a group two times because both the inputparametes are over two weeks.

How can I get for the dates (from t1) the correct opening dates looking the group Begin and End date?

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi: You are right about the join. I added this now. I also added some table data.

Comment: When I have the date 2012-10-29 from table 1 then I still get Two records because of the Input parameters. Im facing with two dateranges which makes difficult to filter just one record. I'm actually excepting in case of 2012-10-29 just the second record from the group table. Please see the Where clause I have.

Comment: I'm expecting both of the columns from table1 but the problem is that they appears two times(I'm getting 4 records). This is because both of the records from Group are between the @begindate/@enddate. I actually need a manner to show the record from table 1 with date 2012-10-23 just once, but in my case this appears two time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a condition between table1 and [group], which is the last line in the query below.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1  
INNER JOIN Combinations c ON t1.Id=c.Table1Id
INNER JOIN [Group] g ON c.GroupId=g.Id  
WHERE t1.Date<= @Enddate AND t1.Date>= @Begindate 
AND g.BeginDate <=@Enddate and g.Enddate >= @Begindate
AND t1.Date between g.BeginDate and g.EndDate
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3d0e8/1/0)

Comment: For a Group I have the following information but I still get two records. I also replaced the NULL value with the @Startdate, but this was not the solution. 

Startdate   Enddate  
2008-01-01 2012-01-01   
2012-01-02  2012-02-06   
NULL         2012-01-01   
2012-01-02  2012-02-05   
2012-02-06  2012-09-02

Comment: Update [this link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3d0e8/1/0) with your data and come back with the new link (bottom after you run your query)

Comment: This is the [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/74afa/3) but I get an error about the scaler variable.

Comment: Both these rows: `'Group A',  '2012-01-02',  '2012-02-06'` **and**
`'Group A',  '2012-01-02',  '2012-02-05'` overlap each other and are legit. Looks more like a data issue. As far as SQL is concerned, they are two separate and distinct events. Otherwise, which do you choose?

Comment: I tried it on my local Sql server and I get a recod twice. I think the problem is with the Start and End date. If you try the code from my link then you will see it.

Comment: Thank you so much, the last where statement helped me also.